# How to use io.read() with LuaSublime?

Tags: lua

I'm using [LuaSublime](https://github.com/rorydriscoll/LuaSublime).

```
a = io.read()
print(a) -- nil
```

It doesn't let me to input anything and just prints nil.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: `io.read()` won't do anything unless you already did an `io.open()` on a file or stream. It does not pop up a dialog or otherwise ask you for input. Do you have other code before and after this code?

Comment: @Adam B It works fine when I'm using cmd.

Comment: I don't see how using a plugin that is supposed to make things "more pleasant" in your text editor would affect this. Anyway, it works fine for me. I copy pasted your code and ran it in it's own Lua file, and it works as expected.

Comment: @Omega it souldn't work like that. I must let me input some text and print it after I press enter. If I'm making it from sublime I can do that, if from cmd I can. That's why do I need cmd.